# Roblox store not deducting money

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a roblox store and when I buy something it will deduct money from my leaderstats but when I go and get some more money, it adds the money I just got along with the money I had just spent. Here is the code that I have

```
local price = script.Parent.Parent.Price
local tools = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Tools")
local tool = script.Parent.Parent.ItemName
local player = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Coins").Value >= price.Value then
        player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Coins").Value = player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Coins").Value - price.Value 
        game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopBuy:FireServer(tool.Value)
    end
end)
```

This is one of the scripts that give you money.

```
db = false
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        if db == false then
            db = true
            script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright red")
            player.leaderstats.Coins.Value = player.leaderstats.Coins.Value + 100
            wait(10)
            script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Dark green")
            db = false

        end
    end
end)
```

It doesn't give me an error it just does what I explained. If you need me to be more specific then just ask! I am new to this so I may not be the best. :) Any help with be much appreciated!

Comment: This code sample doesn't modify the player's money. Could you add that to your question?

Comment: Whooops! Sorry! Yes I can get that to you!

Comment: Ok! I edited it.

Comment: Could you also add the code where you add more money to leaderstats?

Comment: Yep! Just did that

Comment: Anything yet???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be that you are changing the leaderstats value on your client and not on the server in your first script. The server does not know then about that change and will not consider it when doing the other update to your Coins value.

Instead, you should change the Coins value in the ShopBuy event handler that you are invoking in your first script.

Updated:

I think your solution is from a tutorial that has steps on youtube... I haven't gone through those but I would try the following:

In the client script below the buy button, get rid of the line that changes the money, and instead send the price value to the server:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopBuy:FireServer(tool.Value,price.Value)
```

The in the server's ShopBuy script, change the callback signature to include that new parameter, like so:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopBuy.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,tool,price)
```

and then add the line to deduct the money into that function:

```
player.leaderstats.Money.Value = layer.leaderstats.Money.Value - price
```

Think about it. The server is executing the command to do the deduction now, so all the clients will know about it.

One more note on the side: if you create an "IntValue" inside each tool that holds the price of it, you don't need to send the price from a client to the server.

Comment: But that is a RemoteEvent... How would I change that?

Comment: Here is the link to the shop gui so you can play around with it and maybe see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying a store for sooo long and I have never been able to get one to work! I upvoted your answer and clicked the check mark! Once again, thank you so much!